# Can I safely combine my schemas

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a PostgreSQL database in which I am collecting reports from 4 different producers. Back when I wrote this I defined 4 different schemas (one per producer) and since the reports are similar in structure each schema has exactly the same tables inside. I'd like to combine the schemas into one and add an extra column with the producer id to the tables.

At the moment I have 4 python processes running - one per producer. A process collects a report and inserts it in the DB.

My very simple code has been running without crashing for the past few months. The current design makes it impossible for 2 processes to want to insert data into the DB at the same time. If I made the DB changes (single schema with single table) several processes might want to insert data simultaneously. For the moment, I will exclude combining the processes into a single one, please assume I don't do this.

I am unsure if I need to worry about any special code to handle the case of more than one process inserting data into the DB? I am using python3 + SQLAlchemy + Flask. I would imagine the ACID properties of a DB should automatically handle the case of 2 or more processes wanting to insert data simultaneously (data in report is small and insertion will take less than 1s). Can I combine the schemas without worrying about processes insert collisions?

Comment: What kind of db are you using?

Comment: updated: postgres

Comment: What do you define as "large amounts of data"?  How many rows per second?  How many columns are being inserted on each row?  Even a small Linux server (assuming Linux since you said PostgreSQL) should be able to handle hundreds of thousands of INSERTS per second if not more.

Comment: I was asking more of a "in principle" which is a bit irrelevant. I would imagine there might be a scenario in which you try to insert say 100GB via single insert which blocks other inserts for long enough time for them to time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be a problem if you are using a proper db such as Postgres or MySQL. They are designed to handle this.

If you are using sqlite then it could break.

Comment: I would imagine it could be a problem if I am inserting large amounts of data and one insert causes another to timeout?

Comment: @s5s I'm not a db expert, so I cannot say with certainty what kind of limits there are to very large operations. But my very unscientific opinion is that  postgres will generally handle anything you throw at it

Answer (score 0):

For simple INSERTs, yes, you can safely have four producers adding rows. I'm assuming you don't have long running queries, as consistent reads can require allocating an interesting amount of log space if inserts keep happening during an hour-long JOIN.

> if I am inserting large amounts of data and one insert causes another to timeout?

You suggest that a timeout could arise from multiple competing INSERTs, but I don't understand what might produce that. I don't believe that is a problem you have thus far observed. Readers and writers can contend for locks, but independent INSERTing processes are quite safe. If four processes were doing BEGIN, UPDATE 1, ... UPDATE N, COMMIT, then respecting a global order would matter, but your use case has the advantage of being very simple.